# Override httpd.conf and php.ini on shared hosts

Tags: apache-2.2, php, web-hosting, godaddy, shared-hosting

My application needs `mod_rewrite` and `AllowEncodedSlashes` enabled on `httpd.conf`. It also needs some php extensions to be enabled but I can't find how to change those settings on my host's pannel.

Can I do it programatically?

Comment: Have you tried asking Godaddy?

Comment: What do you think? Of course!

Comment: And what was their response?

Comment: I've got no response yet. If they do then I'll post it. I believe they won't for security reasons. That's why I'm asking here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most shared hosts do not allow directly editing `httpd.conf`.

But you can always put those directives in a `.htaccess`

*Update*

If some setting is not allowed by a shared host in your `.htaccess` file, most likely the hosting provider deems it either unsafe or a privilege only for VPS and Dedicated Customers.

But all hosting providers I have dealt with (I never had a hosting account with GoDaddy so cannot speak about them) were flexible if your needs are genuine. So you can always talk to them and try to justify your need for some configuration setting and maybe you can get lucky.

As for the list of available PHP Modules, the only place which can give you an answer is your Hosting Support or the Community forums of the provider, in your case http://community.godaddy.com/

Comment: Unfortunately some settings are not allowed to be put in .htaccess.

Comment: @Eduardo see my update. But in short only one who can really help you is Godaddy Support.